# django filter depeding on character count of the item

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models such that

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False,default="")

class JobTitle(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey(Employer,unique=False,null=False,default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=False,default="")
```

and I would like to get all employers whose jobtitle name is less than X chracters. 
How can I achive this in Django ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `extra`:

```
Emp.objects.extra(select={'name_length': 'LENGTH(`name`)'},
                  where=['name_length < 24'])
```

or `raw`:

```
Emp.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_emp WHERE LENGTH(`name`) < 24')
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer but I have to update my question. How can I solve the problem if my models are as defined in the question?